# Are bcrypt salts accessible separately?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, salt, bcrypt

When using `has_secure_password` in Rails 3.1, bcrypt randomly generates a salt for each user's password. Based on [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277044/do-i-need-to-store-the-salt-with-bcrypt/277057#277057), I understand the salt is stored as part of the password hash. Is there a method or attribute available to access that salt separately, for example to use in writing secure cookies?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You'll be able to get the salt and checksum if you need it.

```
gem install bcrypt-ruby
irb
require 'bcrypt'

hash = BCrypt::Password.create 'superpass'
=> "$2a$10$DtjuZD6nJtrBRLEySlSVm.bJyBMhEhVRAeiVk/GjmQdBNf7WhmDWi"
hash.salt
=> "$2a$10$DtjuZD6nJtrBRLEySlSVm."
hash.checksum
"bJyBMhEhVRAeiVk/GjmQdBNf7WhmDWi"
hash == "starbucks"
=> false
hash == "superpass"
=> true
```

Your salt and checksum will vary.

More info: https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby

Comment: Thanks! With this in mind, plus a look at [the Rails secure_password model](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb), I was able to determine that I needed to write a method for my code (to access the salt neatly, anyway).`def salt
  @salt ||= BCrypt::Password.new(password_digest).salt
end` is perfect!