# migrate from devise passwords to java

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I have system created in rails with devise. I need to rewrite it's authentication logic to java. Problem is, I don't know how is rails encrypted password generated. I need this knowledge to create similar method in java to authenticate against encrypted passwords already strored in database.

Thx for help.

Comment: You should take a look at the devise source code. It's well-commented, so it's not too difficult to see what's going on. A starting point for you might be 'path/to/devise/lib/devise/strategies/authenticatable.rb'.

Comment: I found class, but it looks like wrapper for other library. I'm searching for lines when password from browser (request) is taken and encryptedPassword value is created.

Comment: digging in code of devise, it looks like devise/encryptors/sha512.rb is file where magic happens .. hmm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After couple hours of diging I found that it's enough to use following line:

```
BCrypt.checkpw(plainTextPassword, encryptedPassword)
```

You don't need to understand which part of database stored string is salt, stretches, etc. I still don't fully understand what are the parts of string: `$2a$10$IAB6DfjYD4mbHiGWHB6YAOJqSwie1kLJNTl/bKQasb.ZJ.hj8VdTq` which is devise stored version of `123456` password ;)

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277044/do-i-need-to-store-the-salt-with-bcrypt) helped me to understand what I need to do.

Comment: Is there something similar like Ruby's Devise but in Java?