# Spring's BCrypt implementation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, cryptography, bcrypt

I'm trying to use [Spring's BCrypt implementation](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.1.7.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCrypt.html).  I noticed the `checkpw()` method takes 2 arguments: the plaintext password and the hash.  How is the method able to verify this without the salt being included?

Comment: Why don't you use `BCryptPasswordEncoder` class instead? P.S. See [this question too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277044/do-i-need-to-store-the-salt-with-bcrypt?rq=1).

Comment: Just adding on further the main question is what are you trying to achieve with checkpw() functionality? Furthermore Branislav has pointed out a good answer for a similar question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can verify and it's not magical - the BCrypt encoded hash contains the salt. You can store the salt in a variable to inspect it:

```
String salt = BCrypt.gensalt();
String pw_hash = BCrypt.hashpw(plain_password, salt);

System.out.println(salt);
System.out.println(pw_hash);
```