# How bcrypt.js compare method knows the number of salting rounds?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hash, bcrypt

As the [bcrypt documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt#with-promises) addresses, in order to compare a hash to a plain text we must implement the `compare` function like so:

```
bcrypt.compare(myPlaintextPassword, hash).then(function(result) { //do stuff });
```

but there seems to be no way to tell the function the rounds of salting. How does the functions gets that number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bcrypt output looks like this: `$2a$10$N9qo8uLOickgx2ZMRZoMyeIjZAgcfl7p92ldGxad68LJZdL17lhWy` 
It specifies a cost parameter of 10, indicating 2^10 key expansion rounds. 
The salt is `N9qo8uLOickgx2ZMRZoMye` and the password hash is `IjZAgcfl7p92ldGxad68LJZdL17lhWy`.

So all information that's needed, is input in the `hash` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

> The prefix "$2a$" or "$2b$" (or "$2y$") in a hash string in a shadow
>   password file indicates that hash string is a bcrypt hash in modular
>   crypt format. The rest of the hash string includes the cost
>   parameter, a 128-bit salt (Radix-64 encoded as 22 characters), and 184
>   bits of the resulting hash value (Radix-64 encoded as 31
>   characters).The Radix-64 encoding uses the unix/crypt alphabet,
>   and is not 'standard' Base-64. The cost parameter specifies a
>   key expansion iteration count as a power of two, which is an input to
>   the crypt algorithm.
>
> For example, the shadow password record
>   $2a$10$N9qo8uLOickgx2ZMRZoMyeIjZAgcfl7p92ldGxad68LJZdL17lhWy specifies
>   a cost parameter of 10, indicating 2^10 key expansion rounds. The salt
>   is N9qo8uLOickgx2ZMRZoMye and the resulting hash is
>   IjZAgcfl7p92ldGxad68LJZdL17lhWy. Per standard practice, the user's
>   password itself is not stored.

There is a whole wikipedia entry for this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt